# How do I convert a comma separated list into a <ul>list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a comma separated list into a <ul> list.

HTML

```
<div class="fruit">apple,banana,melon</div>
```

JS

```
$('.fruit').each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(txt.replace(/,/g,'</li><li>'));
}).wrapInner('<ul><li></li></ul>');
```

I expected...

```
<div class="fruit">
    <ul>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>banana</li>
        <li>melon</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But, the result is...

```
<div class="fruit">
    <ul>
        <li>apple
        <li>banana</li>
        <li>melon</li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Why the first comma, between "apple" and "banana", is replaced with only '<li>', and the missing '</li>' moves to the last, behind "melon"?

Or, should I use other methods like split() & join() to get a right result?

Answer (score 3):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$('.fruit').html(function(_, oldHTML) {
   return '<ul><li>' + oldHTML.split(',').join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvGrrW)

```
<div class="fruits">apple,banana,melon</div>



var fruitsNode = document.querySelector('.fruits');
var fruits = fruitsNode.innerHTML.split(',');

var fruitsHTML = [];
fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
  fruitsHTML.push('<li>' + fruit + '</li>');
});

fruitsNode.innerHTML = fruitsHTML.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the first comma, between `"apple"` and `"banana"`, is replaced with only `<li>`, and the missing `</li>` moves to the last, behind `"melon"`?

It's not. That's just the result of the invalid html that you created:

```html
apple</li><li>banana</li><li>melon
```

Which got *parsed* into

```html
apple<li>banana</li><li>melon</li>
```

when you use `.html()`. And that got wrapped into `<ul><li>…</li></ul>` by `.wrapInner` - which leads to the invalid DOM with nested `<li>` tags you're seeing.

> should I use other methods like split() & join() to get a right result?

Yes. I'd recommend

```
$('.fruit').contents().replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<ul>').append($(this.data.split(",")).map(function() {
        return $('<li>').text(this).get();
    }));
})
```

Comment: This is certainly what is happening in Chrome on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you applied `wrapInner` to `each`. Your regex is ok.

To fix it apply `wrapInner` to `html`:

```
    $('.fruit').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).html(txt.replace(/,/g,'</li><li>')).wrapInner('<ul><li></li></ul>');
    });
```

However what you're passing to `wrapInner` is not valid **html**. This doesn't break things but I'd prefer something more clean like this:

```
$('.fruit').each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<ul><li>' + txt.replace(/,/g,'</li><li>') + '</li></ul>');});
```

Comment: OP, you can't add the markup in two steps because the browser tries to fill in the missing markup after the first step (see Bergi's answer for more details). Paolo's got it right. Here's a fiddle showing the result: https://jsfiddle.net/chd41uef/

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you want to do, use a simple (untested) one-liner like  `'<ul><li>' + document.getElementsByClassName("fruit")[0].textContent.replace(',', '</li><li>') + '</li></ul>'`.

On the other hand, if you want to re-use this in different places (dynamic class names, element types, etc) then you would want to refactor into a proper method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Vohuman's method. Here's just another way of doing.. less handy, but still an option.

```
var getContent = $('.fruit').html().split(',');
var list = '<ul>';
$(getContent ).each(function(key,value){
    list += '<li>'+ value +'</li>';
    }

list += '</ul>'; //list now contains a complete list.
```